# Is it possible to get access to PC system via web app using modules like pyautogui and win32gui/pywin32?

Tags: python, django, pandas, pywin32, pyautogui

As a training project i have made  activity tracker using  python (no GUI, only command-line).

Script checks with **win32gui/pywin32** and **pyautogui** what program is currently used, and if it is web browser what web site is in use. 
Name of window, date, and amount of time spent on program/website is stored in sqlite3 database. 
Then with help of **pandas** module same names are grouped and time is summed up.

I want to convert this script into web app using **django** but i am beginner in creating web apps, so i am wondering: is it possible to use this modules within django and is it even possible to create web app that works same as script mentioned earlier?

Sorry if the question is trivial. I will be grateful for every tip where and what exactly to look for in this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.

You can't make a server to connect through a web client/browser and see the other processes. That's a security issue, a big one.

Btw, some GNU/Linux desktop environments won't even allow the same user's processes in the same logged-in session on the same computer to see each other (Wayland).

Comment: Thank you very much, so i'll stay with making desktop app.